# Renaming commands defined in sty files in the preamble

Tags: naming

I want to introduce some command renaming.  It is usually claimed that definitions are to be included in the preamble, with the document text  put within the document body.  What are the considerations that would put the definition of commands within the body, rather than in the preamble?

```
\makeatletter 

\let\pipe\galex@pipe
\let\divid\galex@divid
\let\bfblue\galex@bfblue
\let\nopari\galex@nopari
\let\pari\galex@pari

\makeatother
```

Comment: It should be all right, but some documentclasses or packages will be hooked at the end of the preamble  or after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I am using my own `sty` files.  I suppose there are specific commands for hooking after the preamble.  Right?

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but like most of your question also this one is pretty cryptic. Whether you should do that in the preamble or not depends on what you are actually trying to do, and as your usual you are not very clear about that. I'd say the preamble is fine, but who knows... anyway you can delay code by putting it into `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

Comment: Am not against bluntness.  Will put more detail.

Comment: why would you want definitions in-document at all? place the `\let` commands in `mynames.sty` and use `\usepackage{mynames}` in the preamble, allowing re-use and cleaner document structure.

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: Shall take your re-use and cleaner structure as instructed.  I figured that after using  `\catcode``-=11`, the way to reset it is `\catcode``-=12`.  The question was about some information about situations when one would hook commands after the promable.

Comment: You might sometimes want definitions after begin document but never with @ commands and preferably not using `\let` which is not a latex command.

Comment: Fine, what would be your recommendation instead of `\let`?

Comment: `\newcommand` or (in recent releases) `\NewCommandCopy`

Comment: @ close voters: I actually find this question rather clear, and the comments by Clara and campa contain the core of the answer, which indicates that they understood the question (even before the edit). At least the OP seems to move towards more established coding practises :) Voting to leave open.